# Creating dynamic geometry in GPU vs. CPU?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have a situation where I have lots (thousands at least) of 3D shapes that are clearly defined by a small set of values: mass, center position, angular position, velocity, angular velocity, force, and torque. For example, let's say they are ellipsoids whose shape depends on some of those values. For example, push on a sphere and it "squishes". Spin it fast enough and it gives off an aura or something.

Is this something that would be suitable to push an array of those values to the GPU (if so, what would be best way to push them?), and have shaders (tesselation, geometry, what?) create the geometry from them?

And I'd want other shaders (for effects like HDR and such) to have access to the original values... let's say for example a "comet trail" type of shader so there are streaks coming off in the direction opposite the velocity.

The question again: would pushing the original values to the GPU and let it do everything be the best approach, or would it be better to take some other approach?

Comment: "I have a situation where I have lots (thousands at least) of 3D shapes that are clearly defined by a small set of values: mass, center position, angular position, velocity, angular velocity, force, and torque."... in other words, particles? :) You can do ***stateful*** particle simulation on GPUs these days using textures and fragment shaders, or if you are really bold using compute shaders. And you **definitely** want to do this on the GPU, you can do simulations of upwards of millions of particles at real-time framerates if you use the GPU instead of CPU.

Comment: It depends on what all is included in the term "particles". A complex ellipsoid with separate core and shell and maybe some stuff inside... it's a somewhat complex geometry. Does that still fit with your answer of referring to it as a particle?

Comment: @taotree: it doesn't matter for the actual particle simulation, as you can make a very good approximation by taking them as point masses; the shape only matters for collisions and for air resistance. Ellipsoids are easily described for air resistance using a so called *form factor*. To draw each "particle" you'd use instancing, i.e. each tuple `(center-point, orientation, form-factor)` would trigger the rendering of a complex shape, that has been defined exactly one time, but is used thousands of times then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is so often the case, the answer is "it depends."

In terms of performance, running this on the GPU will most likely be the best approach. As Andon and datenwolf have written, a modern GPU can calculate and update state entirely on the GPU (eg transform feedback and texture buffers), and with point sprites, geometry shaders, and tessellation shaders you can generate complex sprites and shapes entirely on the GPU as well. Still, "most likely" because the golden rule of performance is to always write the code and measure, not guess.

But that's assuming a modern GPU and OpenGL 4. Which won't be available if you want this to run on a tablet, a mobile phone, or MacOS.

Furthermore, what kind of project is this? Are you the sole programmer? If not, are the other programmers (present or future) going to be learning modern GPU programming too?

Assuming you do have OpenGL 4 and want to use it, the OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition has some good sections on how to do calculations and rendering entirely on the GPU.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer. I should have specified I'm only targeting desktops and not mobile devices.